# Authorize Vimeo advanced API

Tags: c#, oauth, vimeo

I'm having a bit of trouble authorizing my Vimeo account through OAuth. I'm using the following .NET wrapper: http://afsharious.wordpress.com/vimeo-for-windows/vimeodotnet/

I understand that the user has to open a browser to get the verification code which is then needed for logging in through the API/wrapper. However, I need to simply list the videos I have on my Vimeo account on a webpage, so I don't want the user to open a new window and do all the verification-code thing described in the tutorial.

Is there any other way of doing it? I have tried by simply using my Consumer key, Consumer secret, my Access token and my Access Token Secret that I get by registrating a new application on Vimeo. However, this does not work, it seems I cannot log in like that :-(

The code I tried was the following:

```
Vimeo.API.VimeoClient vimeoClient = new VimeoClient(MyConsumerKey, MyConsumerSecret);

// Login to Vimeo
vimeoClient.Login(MyAccessToken, MyAccessTokenSecret);

// Get videos
Videos videos = vimeoClient.vimeo_videos_getAll(true, null, null, VimeoClient.VideosSortMethod.Default, MyUserId);
```

Anyone know how to do this? :-)